# Logout button doesn't clear Local Storage

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have created a login which stores a token in the local storage. The logout button I created should delete this token from the local storage and set the user to null, but it doesn't and the user stays logged in.

This is the method in the navbar.component.ts

```
 onLogoutClick(){
    this.authService.logout();
    this.flashMessage.show('You are logged out', {
      cssClass:'alert-success',
      timeout: 3000
    });
```

This is the logout link in the navbar.component.html:

```
<li><a class="nav-link" (click)="onLogOutClick()" href="#">Logout</a></li>
```

The auth.service.ts:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
authToken: any;
user: any;
localUrl : string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
  authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }

  storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  } 

  loggedIn(){
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }
  logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  getProfile(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {headers: headers})
    .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }

  loadToken(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }
}
```

Comment: your function name seems to be case insensitive `onLogOutClick` other than that everything is fine

Comment: So first of all I would never clear the entire localStorage, since other parts of the application could write something into it, and that would be cleared as well. Try `localStorage.removeItem('token')` to remove the token. 
Second: Normally you don't store `user` and `authToken` seperately. For `user` you should create some class/interface which stores all the values, and then also assign its type instead of `any`, so the compiler can assist you.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: localForage may be a better solution. Lets you store objects too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue, as stated by [syed-mohamed-aladeen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4354201/syed-mohamed-aladeen), is that you named your function `onLogoutClick` but bound to the click event `onLogOutClick` with a capital O.

Functions are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

The context of your handler may be affecting it. Instead of clearing local storage, you should selectively remove items.

```
logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.clear()` should achieve the same result. This is not an answer to the problem. What if he adds more data later on?